# Работа с координатами на карте

Tags: математика, php, координаты, карты

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки!
Вопрос из области тригонометрии.
Самолет летит из точки А в точку Б. У обеих точек есть координаты (долгота, широта):

```
$a['latitude'] = '95.971786120237';
$a['longitude'] = '47.251077912615';

$b['latitude'] = '75.971786120237';
$b['longitude'] = '22.251077912615';
```

Есть информация, сколько процентов пути пройдено.
Также есть данные о том, какое расстояние в метрах от точки А к точке Б.

Исходя из этих данных, нужно максимально точно вычислить координаты точки Х - где сейчас находиться самолет.

Простая арифметика, типа:

```
$x['latitude'] = $a['latitude'] - $b['latitude'] * на количество процентов + $a['latitude'];
```

и аналогично с longitude

не подходит, так как на длинных сегментах точность очень низкая, и отклонение от маршрута бывает слишком большое.

Подозреваю, нужно копать в сторону синусов, котангенсов, учитывать радиус земли и т.д.
Есть идеи? Заранее очень благодарен!

Comment: Высота не учитывается вовсе? К тому же по прямой далеко не все самолеты летают, особенно на дальние расстояния через воздушное пространство разных стран.

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам решение для случая, если считать Землю строго сферической.

Вы считаете расстояние по большому кругу по одной из [этих формул](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Computational_formulas). Поделив на радиус, получаете центральный угол между точками отправления и прибытия. Умножив на текущий процент, получаете центральный угол между точкой отправления и текущей позицией. Пусть этот угол α. Остаток угла пусть будет β.

Далее, вам нужно отложить от центра Земли вектор (обозначим его ***x***) под нужным углом между двумя векторами: первый соединяет центр Земли с точкой отправления (пусть это будет ***a***), а второй — с точкой прибытия (пусть это будет ***b***). Это чистая геометрия на плоскости. Можете сделать, например, так.

Разложим вектор ***x*** по векторам ***a*** и ***b***. Пусть ***x*** = *p****a*** + *q****b***.

[image: разложение векторов и теорема синусов, уроки Кушнира не прошли даром]

Как учили на уроках геометрии:

*pR* / sin β == *R* / sin (α + β)

то есть

*p* = sin β/sin (α + β)

Аналогично

*q* = sin α/sin (α + β)

Дерзайте!

Comment: Очень благодарен за ответ!
Есть еще просьба, не могли бы вы записать данные расчеты на PHP?

Comment: @axejko: Не-а, я совсем не знаю PHP. Но сложно быть не должно.

Comment: А какой нибудь язык знаете? Дело в том, что я пробовал подставить Ваши формулы, но в итоге самолет летит или в другую сторону, или ровно по экватору, или вообще не туда(

Comment: @axejko: Извините, лень как-то. А как именно вы подставляли? Вы не ошиблись в сложении векторов?